# Where condition execution sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.0.88. I have a query like

```
select DISTINCT party.­id FROM party­ LEFT join party_­identifier AS pi ON pi.­party_­id = party.­id­ WHERE ­(pi.­source_­note=? AND first_­name LIKE ? OR last_­name LIKE ? OR pi.­identifier LIKE ?)­ AND party.­type = ? AND party.­record_­status_­id = ?
```

Here what my doubt is if suppose Pi.source_note result becomes false means the rest of the condition will execute or not (In point of SQL NOT programming languages).